# Instantiating template with subclass of template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement a Game Engine in C/C++ for a class project. I've decided to use [the acyclic visitor pattern](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuze6q_qrRAhUE6CwKHV1FABsQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcondor.depaul.edu%2Fdmumaugh%2FOOT%2FDesign-Principles%2Facv.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHKIOpKWCfJajDK5BwWFG7W6vTljQ&sig2=XsuoP8j2A-qycMTfXMNsRQ) for sending events between the subsystems since I need to be able to be extend the set of events and subsystems outside of the engine. I would like to use templates for some parts of this since a lot of the code is the same with just different types as arguments. When creating a new event I would like to inherit from the `Event` class template and then instantiating it with the subclass:

```
// Event.h
template<typename T>
class Event {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Event, T>::value);
public:
    void Event::accept(EventListenerBase& el){
        if (EventListener<T>* eventListener = dynamic_cast<EventListener<T>*>(*el)){
        eventListner->accept(this);
        }
    }
};

// MyNewEvent.h 
class MyNewEvent : public Event<MyNewEvent>  {

}
```

Is this a viable solution?

Comment: `Would this be possible?`: have you tried it? What tells you the compiler?

Comment: Also think of providing [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is kind of hard to predict if `EventListener<T*>` has overloaded cast to `T*` operator or is it your code's bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, and there is actually a name for this pattern: Curiously recurring template pattern (or CRTP).

And btw. this is not specializing the template, but instantiating it. A specialization would be

```
template<>
class Event<MyNewEvent> { /* ... */ };
```